# Error: Unexpected element '*' in format string at (1)

Tags: fortran, format

I am using 'mpifort' for the compilation. Here is part of the code which raises the error.

```
2004    format(a30,*(f10.6))
```

When compiling, I get the following error for this code segment.

```
DI.f90:320.20:

2004    format(a30,*(f10.6))
                    1
Error: Unexpected element '*' in format string at (1)
```

What could be the error? When compiling with intel's 'mpiifort' there is no problem at all.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenMPI, this is caused by the Fortran compiler that is called in the process. You can install OpenMPI for your Intel Compiler. You should tell us, which compiler does your 'mpifort' call. Try running `mpifort -v`.

Comment: The code requires a MPI fortran compiler. Regarding @francescalus question, the underlyinh fortran compiler is 'gfortran'. Probably it means that gfortran does not support this unlimited-format-item. But does gfortran support any similar?

Comment: Gfortran does support it, but you have some old version. Most likely you are using some old RedHat server with an ancient GCC distribution. Actually, there are no MPI Fortran compilers. MPI is an additional library. The compilers knows nothing at all about MPI.

Comment: According to the [gfortran wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status), " Yes (since 4.5, 2009-08-17) "

Answer (score 4):

In a format the `*(..)` represents an unlimited format item.  It was a feature introduced in Fortran 2008 and is not supported by all (versions of all) compilers.  When you are using `mpifort` you call an underlying Fortran compiler (with certain options specified), so you may want to choose a compiler which understands this Fortran feature.  You'll see that recent Intel compilers do understand this (and recent GCC compilers do also).

Alternatively, if you haven't access to such a compiler then you can simply modify the code to use earlier features:

```
2004    format(a30,9999(f10.6))
```

(for some suitably large repeat count): the `*` acts as just a very large repeat count.